# How jasmine spy example works

Tags: testing, jasmine

All;

I am just starting learning Jasmine( version 2.0.3 ), when I got to Spies section, the first example confused me:

```
describe("A spy", function() {
  var foo, bar = null;

  beforeEach(function() {
    foo = {
      setBar: function(value) {
        bar = value;
      }
    };

    spyOn(foo, 'setBar');

    foo.setBar(123);
    foo.setBar(456, 'another param');
  });

  it("tracks that the spy was called", function() {
    expect(foo.setBar).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it("tracks all the arguments of its calls", function() {
    expect(foo.setBar).toHaveBeenCalledWith(123);
    expect(foo.setBar).toHaveBeenCalledWith(456, 'another param');
  });

  it("stops all execution on a function", function() {
    expect(bar).toBeNull();
  });
});
```

I wonder if anyone could explain **why the setBar function does not affect the bar defined inside describe block?** How Jasmine spies deal with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are not actually executing the methods.

If you want this test to fail:

```
it("stops all execution on a function", function() {
    expect(bar).toBeNull();
});
```

After these calls:

```
foo.setBar(123);
foo.setBar(456, 'another param');
```

Then you should call `and.callThrough` for your spy.

```
spyOn(foo, 'setBar').and.callThrough();
```

From the [documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html)

> **Spies: and.callThrough**
>
> By chaining the spy with and.callThrough, the spy will still track all
>   calls to it but in addition it will delegate to the actual
>   implementation.

With regard to your question, 'how jasmine deals with this?'

From [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/spy-on-javascript-methods-using-the-jasmine-testing-framework.html#fbid=6Fh8x8WmF37) you can read a basic explanation:

> Mocks work by implementing the proxy pattern. When you create a mock
>   object, it creates a proxy object that takes the place of the real
>   object. We can then define what methods are called and their returned
>   values from within our test method. Mocks can then be utilized to
>   retrieve run-time statistics on the spied function such as:
>
> ```
> How many times the spied function was called.
> What was the value that the function returned to the caller.
> How many parameters the function was called with.
> ```

If you want all of the implementation details, you can check the Jasmine source code which is [Open Source](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine) :)

In this source file [CallTracker](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/CallTracker.js) you can see how the gather data about the method calls.

A little more about [the proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).

Comment: Thanks, what interests me most is how Jasmine achieve this by without running actual function and affecting according variables? Basically how dose it copy everything into its isolated scope(if my understanding about this is right)? Could you give me some more detail about that?

Comment: Thanks, I read http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/proxy_pattern.htm  From my understanding, it is basically use a inner object to delegate a task. But I kinda wondering how to related my example to this  pattern.

Comment: @Cacho Santa: I have an issue to get data from controller can you please look into it. Can you help me on it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53629138/how-to-test-and-resolve-controller-data-then-function-promise-and-get-orgin