# how to test and resolve Controller data (.then function()) promise and get orginal Data in Jasmine2

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine, jasmine2.0

```
    I am testing a controller that uses a service that returns a promise. I need to resolve promise. I am using Jasmine 2. 

    Here is Spec code

      beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _myService_, _$q_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_, $http) {


         scope = $rootScope.$new();
         $q = _$q_;
         $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
         $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
         myService = _myService_;
$http = $http;
         ctrl =  $controller('Ctrl', { '$scope': scope, 'myService': myService });
     spyOn(myService, "getDateRangeData").and.callThrough();

      }));


        it('getDateRangeData return Data obj', function() {

    myService.getDateRangeData().then(function(response) {
      console.log('Success', response);
    }); 
        scope.$digest()      

      });

service js
function getDateRangeData(obj) {
  return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https:URL',
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'X-Auth-Token': self.token
     },
    data: obj
  })
}
```

console not returning any obj.Shows error.Unexpected request: POST https:URL
        No more request expected. i need data from Ctrl . 
In Crtl I am getting data but not in testcase. deferred. how to get Api data. Api data is object. or there is another aprroch to get Ctrl return promise to resolve and getData? added sevice js code where request send.

can anyone help soon please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the spyOn to actually use the correct implementation instead of the mock you can use `callThrough()` instead of `callFake()`.

Try it like this:

```
spyOn(myService, "getDateRangeData").and.callThrough();
```

Comment: Yes tried that and shows error Unexpected request: POST "URL Link" is shown
        No more request expected. Without Spy can I get Ctrl data?

Comment: @Ajay.k the callThrough will actually perform the operations that getDateRangeData() do. Make sure you have specified in your beforeEach what the dependencies on myService should do when they are called. For example, if you inject and use $http in that service, you need to define what it should return when a specific url is called to it.

Comment: tried and updated code. still error is same. and placed var to check then function  it returns Promise{$$state: Object{status: 0}} it is not resolving my promise

Comment: @Höglund: Tried with sample API still I am getting same error  Unexpected request: GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
        No more request expected
        error properties: Object({ $$passToExceptionHandler: true }) can please let me know where i am making mistake?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are "spying on" the wrong method.
We use `spyOn` for two reasons:

- To `expect(method).toHaveBeenCalled`
- To mock the `return value`

In your case the `spyOn` does not achieve any of these two.

You should `spyOn` the `$http` instead. Since the actual http call is not required for your test, the reason being: the objective is not to test `$http`.

```
this.$http = $http;
spyOn(this, '$http').and.callFake(function(args) {
    return {
        then: function(fn) {
            return fn('response');
        }
    };
});
```

And in `it` block:

```
it('getDateRangeData return Data obj', function() {
    myService.getDateRangeData('test')
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log('Success', response);
        expect(response).toEqual('response');
    });
    expect(this.$http).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith('test');   
});
```

Comment: @ Sree.Bh Thanks for reply.I have tried this but promise is not resolved nothing print in console and getting an error expect(...).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith is not a function